Python, Fitting into a system of equations
I am trying to fit my data into a system of two equations like below:


Here I have gamma versus C_s, and rest of them, gamma_0, Gamma_inf, a, and K are fitting parameters.
I don't see any error, But the fitting does not work, and every parameters cannot be negative but some of them are negative.

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Prompt the user for the CSV file location
csv_file = input("Enter the path to your CSV file: ")

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,header=None)

# Alternatively, select each column by index
# Remember that indices start from 0
Cs_data = df.iloc[:, 0]
gamma_data = df.iloc[:, 1]

# Define the Frumkin equilibrium function to solve for x
def frumkin_x(C_s, a, K, x_guess=0.5):
    # Function to find the root of
    func = lambda x: x - C_s / (C_s + a * np.exp(K * x))
    x_solution, = fsolve(func, x_guess)
    return x_solution

# Define the equilibrium isotherm function
def equilibrium_isotherm(C_s, gamma_0, Gamma_inf, a, K):
    x = np.array([frumkin_x(cs, a, K) for cs in C_s])
    return gamma_0 + Gamma_inf * R * T * (np.log(1 - x) - 0.5 * K * x**2)

# Constants
R = 8.314  # Universal gas constant, J/(mol*K)
T = 298    # Temperature, K

# Initial parameter guesses for curve_fit
# gamma_0, Gamma_inf, a, K
initial_guesses = [72, 0.0000000004, 0.00000007, 0]

params_opt, params_cov = curve_fit(lambda Cs, gamma_0, Gamma_inf, a, K: equilibrium_isotherm(Cs, gamma_0, Gamma_inf, a, K), Cs_data, gamma_data, p0=initial_guesses)

# Print optimized parameters
print("Optimized Parameters:")
print("gamma_0:", params_opt[0])
print("Gamma_inf:", params_opt[1])
print("a (alpha_0/beta_0):", params_opt[2])
print("K:", params_opt[3])

# Plot the original data and fitted curve for visualization
Cs_fit = np.linspace(min(Cs_data), max(Cs_data), 100)
gamma_fit = equilibrium_isotherm(Cs_fit, *params_opt)

plt.scatter(Cs_data, gamma_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(Cs_fit, gamma_fit, label='Fitted Curve', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Sublayer Concentration (Cs)')
plt.ylabel('Surface Tension (gamma)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

I did not see any errors, so I cannot figure out what is the problem.
above link contains my script and data.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please add your code to the question, so that contributors don't have to click through to an external website to view your code.

Sorry Nick. I posted my full code.

@WoojinJung note you're ignoring everything fsolve returns other than the solution (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html). In particular the ier and mesg return failure info which you should always check before using x.

@David Waterworth Thank you. I will keep in mind with that.

With a little bit of help, essentially bounds and initial guess (fsolve and curve_fit), you can regress your parameters:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

data = pd.read_csv("frumkin.csv", header=None, names=["Cs", "gamma"])

def system(x, Cs, a, K):
    return x - Cs / (Cs + a * np.exp(K * x))

R = 8.314
T = 298.

def model(Cs, g0, Ginf, a, K):
    x = np.array([optimize.fsolve(system, x0=0.05, args=(c, a, K))[0] for c in Cs])
    return g0 + Ginf * R * T * (np.log(1. - x) - 0.5 * K * x ** 2)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(
    model, data.Cs, data.gamma,
    p0=[100., 1e-5, 1e-5, 1.],
    bounds=[(0., 0., 0., 0.), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)]
)
# array([7.28040792e+01, 3.58127986e-01, 1.43487197e-08, 3.72400451e+02])

It returns:

About uniqueness of the solution, one can show that it is a valid hypothesis over the parameter ranges. Following abacus show relationship between Cs and x for different setup:
@np.vectorize
def solution(Cs, a, K):
    return optimize.fsolve(system, x0=0.05, args=(Cs, a, K))[0]

Cs = np.logspace(-12, -6, 100, base=10)
As = np.logspace(-12, -6, 10, base=10)
Ks = np.logspace(-5, +5, 10, base=10)
C, A, K = np.meshgrid(Cs, As, Ks, indexing="ij")

s = solution(C, A, K)




This is just pure amazing. Thank you so much. There are so many things to learn.

It seems like the curve_fit may be failing because of the nature of the relationship between x and Cs. I haven't delved into it too much, but it's possible that the fact that there may be multiple or no x values for a given Cs value could violate the assumptions made by the underlying curve-fit algorithm. Keep in mind that even if the relationship behaves well for your values, the curve_fit algorithm is likely sampling at values where the relationship does not behave as well.
I can't guarantee that this would work, but I would recommend taking a deeper look into the behavior of the Cs to x relationship. I'm not familiar with the science you're doing here, but if this is a case where there should be a 1-1 mapping between Cs and x, you may want to look into ways to ensure that the frumkin_x solution always picks the correct "x" value, even when multiple solutions satisfy the equation.

Over the ranges of the parameter, one can show numerically than solutions are unique.
